# Is this sheaf simple?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a surface and $C$ be an effective divisor in $S$. That is $C$ is a curve in $S$ and $i:C\longrightarrow S$ is the inclusion morphism. Let $E$ be line bundle over $C$, so $i_*E$ is a coherent sheaf over $S$. Since $E$ is a line bundle, $E$ is simple. Does that mean $i_*E$ is simple too?

In commutative algebra terms, it translates to the following. Let $f: A\longrightarrow A/I$ be a ring homomorphism, and $M$ is a free module of rank 1 over $A/I$. $M$ is simple as an $A/I$ module, that is it has no nontrivial endomorphisms. Is $M$ simple as an $A$ module?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity when can $R$ be a simple $R$-module? If it is so, then $R\simeq R/\mathfrak m$ with $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal, hence $\operatorname{Ann}_R(R)=\operatorname{Ann}_R(R/\mathfrak m)$ and thus we have $\mathfrak m=(0)$. It follows that $R$ is a field.

If $R=A/I$ we get $I$ is maximal, and since $M\simeq A/I\Rightarrow$ $M$ is a simple $A$-module.

Comment: I don't understand. Should $R$ necessarily be a field?

Comment: @poorna Without any doubt.

Comment: By simple $R$ module, you mean $End_R(M)$ has only scalars right?

Comment: Does it mean $i_*E$ is a simple sheaf over  $S$?

Comment: @poorna By a simple module I understand [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_module).